# Does it make sense to turn a closed Mac upside down when it's hot?

Tags: macbook-pro, temperature

After some period of work with my MacBook Pro its bottom part can be hot.

If I want to take a break and close the Mac - does it make sense to turn it around - the bottom part will be on top. Is it better for the working of the fan?

I have seen some users turn their notebooks around the way that the bottom part doesn't have contact with the surface anymore.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106763/discussion-on-question-by-mikrodel-does-it-make-sense-to-turn-a-closed-mac-upsid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to do anything special with regards to your Mac *feeling* hot. Your Mac's fans are managed by the System Management Controller (SMC) which will ensure that your CPU etc are protected in the event your Mac overheats to the point that it could cause damage.

Your question doesn't actually specify what temperature your Mac is at, so it's impossible to comment on whether it's too high. However, MBP models *usually* range from about 40ºC (104ºF) to 100ºC (212ºF) depending on whether the CPU is idle or under load. CPU temps (just like ambient temperatures) typically have a bearing on GPU temps too, especially within the extremely confined spaces of a MacBook.

If you'd like, you can refer to the [Intel Mac Temperature Database](https://www.intelmactemp.com/list) to see the various temperature ranges reported by users. You can also filter the list by model etc.

If you're still concerned, you can also [Reset the System Management Controller (SMC) on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201295) to see if this has any noticeable impact on what you're experiencing.

Comment: If I use MacBook on my knees. I have trousers, but no extra material between trousers or jeans and notebook. Is it ok? The same question for the notebook, that is placed on bed (sofa).

Comment: From the point of view of your MacBook, that is fine. But if you're finding the heat too uncomfortable for your lap, then I can understand you wanting an extra layer of protection between you and the underside of your laptop. But purely from the point of view of your MBP, the SMC is designed to do a lot of things, including protecting your Mac from any overheating.

Comment: That said, if you're in the habit of using your MBP in clamshell mode, and you're frequently doing CPU-intensive work (or you're working in a hot environment), then a stand such as what bmike is referring to will improve airflow. The reduction in temperature that will achieve is only small, but it may mean that in extreme cases any thermal throttling is reduced. Otherwise, as I say in my answer, *there is no need to do anything special with regards to your Mac feeling hot*.

Answer (score 2):

You are right about the metal MacBook Pro case running measurably cooler with room to breathe under high heat generation loads. I prefer to make a small air gap so the airflow out is still with the keyboard horizontal if you don't have a [fancy horizontal](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01F01GO94) or [fancy vertical stand](https://www.twelvesouth.com/product/bookarc-for-macbook). Small air gap is a pencil or two under the back side if you have a stable desk.

[image]

If you do have a fancy vertical stand (twelve south), I've never been able to measure a temperature difference between having the hinge on the bottom or the hinge on the top. I also have never seen a case where simply having it horizontal on a flat surface overheated or damaged a Mac, but if I can keep it measurably cooler with a vertical case, I spend that money every time to be secure and tidy.

Now that you're running in closed clamshell mode, the entire bottom surface is exposed to let radiation and convection remove as much heat as the ambient temperature can allow.

Comment: I can understand the argumentation for up side down position, but is there any proof that sideways actually helps ? of course with the exception of leaving the fans and openings free

Comment: It's not enough to merely put it vertical. It needs to be put "exhaust vent up". That will improve cooling: having convection aid the fan.

Comment: @rsf. In my testing, the temperature is the same no matter which of the four edges is in the stand at the bottom. All the benefit is due to radiative cooling as opposed to convection being better where the blowers exhaust. This might be different on gear newer than the 2015 model 15” MacBook Pro. I’ll accept all loners and donations to do more testing with new MacBooks Pro.